# Real World Haskell : is the use of fromIntegral unnecessary in this example?

Tags: haskell

I don't see why `fromIntegral` is needed in the picture shown below when the return type of `getNat` is `Maybe(Int, L.ByteString)`.

The return type of `L8.readInt` is `Int` so why is conversion needed from `Int` to `Int` ?

Is this a "typo" in the book?

Or am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: AFAICT the `fromIntegral` is not needed, as you say.

Comment: It seems to be unnessesary. The comments in the online version RWH say that the result type of `L8.readInt` was `Maybe (Int64, L.ByteString)`, so that could be the reason why it is there.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation !